# Scraping JSON from a password protected forum in R

Tags: r, json, rvest, httr, jsonlite

I have a problem reading data from a JSON file on a forum that requires login to access.

I am using rvest package and to read an html page after login this code works well. But my doubt is how I read a JSON file using the same session where the user is already registered.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

  url       <- "https://forum.com/"
  pgsession <- html_session(url)
  pgform    <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]] 
  
  filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                            "username" = "username", 
                            "password" = "password")
  
  submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
  

  events <- jump_to(pgsession, "https://forum.com/events.php") 
  page <- html(events)
  data_usernames <- html_text(page, trim = FALSE)
```

Is there any method to read Json using the session? How can I make this code below work

```
  urlJson <- "https://forum.com/events.json"
  
  data = jsonlite::fromJSON(urlJson, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) 
  df <- as.data.frame(data$data)
```

Comment: Every website is different. There isn't much that will work in all cases unless you using something like RSelenium to control a web browser. It's impossible to say what might work without a reproducible example. Also be sure to consult the terms of service for the website you are interacting with. Sometimes scraping password protected forums is against the terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figure it out. Basically using the jump_to method with session and parse_json instead fromJSON everything works as I wanted.

```
  jsonSession <- pgsession %>% jump_to(urlJson) 
  data <- jsonlite::parse_json(jsonSession$response, simplifyVector = TRUE)
  df <- as.data.frame(data$data)
```